Proof about adjoint matrix
Prove: If $A_{n\times n}$ is not invertible then $Adjoint(A)$ is not invertible also.
I have made the following:
By contradiction.
Suppose that $Adj(A)^{-1}$ exists
Then write $Adj(A)*B=I$
\begin{align}
   det(Adj(A)\cdot B)       &= det(I) \\
   det(Adj(A)) \cdot det(B) &= 1 \\
                     det(B) &= \frac{1}{det(Adj(A))} \\
                            &= \frac{1}{det(A)^{n-1}} \\ 
                            &= \frac{1}{0}  \text{Contradiction}
\end{align}
Im not sure all about the proof. It is correct to use that $det(Adj(A))=det(A)^{n-1}$ i know this is a fact. However,(im not sure) in the proof is used that $A^{-1}$ exists

The proof as written is a little awkward, but it can be easily patched up to be correct. Note that what you've shown so far is essentially that $\det A$ is non-zero if $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is invertible. You should know the fact that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det A \neq 0$, so you've proven that $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ being invertible implies that $A$ is invertible. This is equivalent to the statement you want to prove (it is the contrapositive).

Just getting this off the unanswered list.
As @EuYu noted, your proof is a little awkward but could be cleaned up to be correct. I would argue that part of the reason it's awkward is that $\det(\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A))=\det(A)^{n-1}$ is more than you need to establish your result -- see the more direct proof here for example.
I'll add that $\det(\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A))=\det(A)^{n-1}$ can be proved for a "generic matrix" $A$ with indeterminate entries, which shows that it's a polynomial identity and therefore holds for any, not necessarily invertible, "scalar matrix" $A$ by substitution -- see here.
Finally I'll add that you can prove much more: the rank of $\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)$ drops off quickly as the rank of $A$ drops -- see here for example.

Restatement of the Problem to Make it Easier to View in the Answer

Prove: If $A_{n\times n}$ is not invertible then $Adjoint(A)$ is not invertible also.
I have made the following:
By contradiction.
Suppose that $Adj(A)^{-1}$ exists
Then write $Adj(A)*B=I$
$$
\begin{align}
   det(Adj(A)\cdot B)       &= det(I) \\
   det(Adj(A)) \cdot det(B) &= 1 \\
                     det(B) &= \frac{1}{det(Adj(A))} \\
                            &= \frac{1}{det(A)^{n-1}} \\ 
                            &= \frac{1}{0}  \text{Contradiction}
\end{align}
$$
I am not sure all about the proof. It is correct to use that $det(Adj(A))=det(A)^{n-1}$ i know this is a fact. However,(I am not sure) in the proof is used that $A^{-1}$ exists

Answer Solution Steps
First, division by zero is not defined.  So the proof needs to deal with this issue.
From the quote in "Cramer's Rule":

Let A be an n × n matrix with entries in a field F. Then
$${\displaystyle A\,\operatorname {adj} (A)=\operatorname {adj} (A)\,A=\det(A)I}$$
... If $\det(A)$ is nonzero, then the inverse matrix of A is
$${\displaystyle A^{-1}={\frac {1}{\det(A)}}\operatorname {adj} (A).}$$

This can be rewritten as:
$${\det(A)}\,{\displaystyle A^{-1}=\operatorname {adj} \left(A\right).}$$
The "adjoint" (also known as the Adjugate matrix) $\operatorname {adj} \left(A\right)=C^T$ (the transpose of the matrix C) *is always defined * as follows:

$${\displaystyle \mathbf {C} ={\begin{bmatrix}C_{11}&C_{12}&\cdots &C_{1n}\\C_{21}&C_{22}&\cdots &C_{2n}\\\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\C_{n1}&C_{n2}&\cdots &C_{nn}\end{bmatrix}}}$$
One can write down the inverse of an invertible matrix by computing its  cofactors by using Cramer's rule, as follows. The matrix formed by all of the cofactors of a square matrix A is called the cofactor matrix (also called the matrix of cofactors or, sometimes, comatrix):

The case with $A_{x\times x}$ not being invertable occurs when $A_{x\times x}$ is not uniquely defined.
From: $${\det(A)}\,{\displaystyle A^{-1}=\operatorname {adj} \left(A\right).}$$
From here, only if ${\det(A)}=0$, then the matrix $A$ can take on any value with the product $\left({\det(A)}=0\right)\,{\displaystyle A^{-1}=0}$.  So only if ${\det(A)}=0$, since $A_{n\times n}$ is not unique, it is not invert-able.  Also in this case:
$$0\,A^{-1}=\operatorname {adj} \left(A\right)=0$$
Then since ${\operatorname {adj} \left(A\right)=0}$ is a zero matrix, it is not invertable since matrix division by a zero matrix is not defined. Technically there is also the case where $Adj(A)$ is defined, but a zero matrix.  In that case either $Det(A)=0$ which results in $A$ not being invertable since it is a zero $nxn$ matrix.
Or $det(A)=0$ resulting in $A$ not being invertable since zero times any matrix has the same result as a zero matrix, and therefore within the limitation that the determinant is zero, $A$ is not unique.  For $A$ to be invert-able, it must be unique.  Distinct examples resulting in a zero determinant are, for example, for any two rows to be the same value.

Since  $A_{n\times n}$ is not invertible then $Adjoint(A)$ is not
invertible also.

